# Sliding image becomes bigger in carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this [site](http://www.ziiweb.com). The carousel is made with bootstrap 3, bus as you can see the sliding image becomes bigger, why?

This is the code:

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide container">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <img src="images/conejo4.jpg" class="item active " />
        <img src="images/conejo4.jpg" class="item" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE**: I found it, this the code that works:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/conejo4.jpg" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/conejo4.jpg" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) that produces the problem please?

Comment: it is because the width is by default 100%..set the width as per your requirement